# SQL Financial Year Query

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to be able to have this query running daily selecting only where **central_enquiry.enquiry_time** is in the current financial year. The financial year runs from 01/04/YYYY to 31/03/YYYY. Ideally this would be dynamic so that I wouldn't have to manually change the dates next April

```
SELECT
  central_enquiry.enquiry_number,
  central_enquiry.enquiry_name,
  central_enquiry.enquiry_time
FROM
  central_enquiry
WHERE
  central_enquiry.enquiry_time
```

Comment: Do you want a FinancialYear table? Well where I work we usually have a company table and on this table we have the initial and ending dates for each company. You also can have a a table to hold dates for each year

Comment: @jean I'm not sure what I would need i'm afraid! I'm self taught so any recommendations welcome. I already have a table for financial year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with start_date (d) as ( select
  case when current_timestamp < CONVERT(datetime,
          cast(datepart(yyyy, current_timestamp) as varchar) +
          '-04-01T00:00:00.000', 126)
    then convert(datetime,
           cast(datepart(yyyy, current_timestamp) - 1 as varchar)
           + '-04-01T00:00:00.000', 126)
    else convert(datetime,
           cast(datepart(yyyy, current_timestamp) as varchar) +
          '-04-01T00:00:00.000', 126)
  end )
SELECT central_enquiry.enquiry_number,
       central_enquiry.enquiry_name,
       central_enquiry.enquiry_time
    FROM central_enquiry, start_date sd
    WHERE central_enquiry.enquiry_time >= sd.d
      AND central_enquiry.enquiry_time <  dateadd(yyyy,1,sd.d)
```

This should always select data for the current book year.

Comment: Hi Gerard - do you know how to make this dynamic in that when it gets to April next year i don't have to make any changes to the SQL?

Comment: Don't you fear you might be out of a job, next year?

Comment: Not that i'm aware ha! If possible I wanted to make it future proof  so to say!

Comment: @ChrisJenner if you use this, it will be dynamic (assuming you have 2012+ 
  SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy0401');

Comment: Thank you @MguerraTorres - how would that look in the above script?

Comment: I gave it a try, but perhaps MT's solution is a lot easier.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille your solution works perfectly for me! Thank you!

Comment: @GerardH.Pille More or less the same complexity.  Yours definitely works for Pre-2012.    Here's my dynamic one (which also converts to Datetime for optimization:  SELECT 
  CASE 
  WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())<4 
  THEN  CAST(CAST((FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy'+'0401'))-10000 AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME)
  ELSE CAST(FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy-04-01') AS DATETIME)
  END

Comment: Why FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy'+'0401') but FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy-04-01') ? Is 'yyyy0401' a valid format? How does SQL Server know that '20101001' starts with year and century?

Answer (score 0):

This code should give you what you need

```
SELECT central_enquiry.enquiry_number,
       central_enquiry.enquiry_name,
       central_enquiry.enquiry_time
    FROM central_enquiry
    WHERE central_enquiry.enquiry_time >= DATEADD(MM,3,DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, 0,DATEADD(MM,-3,GETDATE())),0))
      AND central_enquiry.enquiry_time <  DATEADD(MM,15,DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, 0,DATEADD(MM,-3,GETDATE())),0))
```

The idea is that no matter what calendar year you are in, if you subtract 3 months you'll still be in the calendar year that corresponds to the start of the financial year. this removes the need for CASE statements.

Comment: Thank you for this @pacreely - I managed to get the below solution to work for me.